# autoValue in SimpleSchema for update does not set given value

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I am using below field in SimpleSchema,

```
  "fileNo": {
    type: String,
    label: "File No.",
    autoValue: function() {
      console.log('this', this);
      console.log('typeof this.value.length ', typeof this.value.length);
      console.log('this.value.length ', this.value.length, this.value.length === 0, this.value.length == 0);
      console.log('this.value ', this.value, typeof this.value);
      console.log('this.operator ', this.operator);
      console.log('this.isSet ', this.isSet);
            if ( this.isSet && 0 === this.value.length ) {
                console.log('if part ran.');
                return "-";
            } else {
              console.log('else part ran.');
            }
        },
    optional:true
  },
```

I am using `autoform` to `update` a field. The problem is when I am updating the field with empty string *(i.e. keeping textbox empty)*, the value `-` is not set as per field definition in SimpleSchema code above.

I get logs as below,

```
clients.js:79 this {isSet: true, value: "", operator: "$unset", unset: ƒ, field: ƒ, …}
clients.js:80 typeof this.value.length  number
clients.js:81 this.value.length  0 true true
clients.js:82 this.value   string
clients.js:83 this.operator  $unset
clients.js:84 this.isSet  true
clients.js:86 if part ran.
clients.js:79 this {isSet: true, value: "-", operator: "$unset", unset: ƒ, field: ƒ, …}
clients.js:80 typeof this.value.length  number
clients.js:81 this.value.length  1 false false
clients.js:82 this.value  - string
clients.js:83 this.operator  $unset
clients.js:84 this.isSet  true
clients.js:89 else part ran.
```

and my collection document does not have field `fileNo`.

**What am I missing? all I want is when value of `fileNo` is `empty/undefined` value must be set to `-` (hyphen)**. In document it must look like `fileNo : "-"`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Styx: modified last line with bold. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, the `defaultValue` is what you do need?

Comment: that too does not work. as `this.isSet` is `true`, so already it is taking `empty` string so it does not use `defaultValue`.

Comment: What version of `simple-schema` are you using?

Comment: I am using `aldeed:autoform@6.2.0` with `simpl-schema": "^0.3.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle 2 situations:

1. Document `insert` with empty (undefined) `value` for `fileNo`.
2. Document `update` with empty `value` for `fileNo`.

In second case, validator will try to remove the field from the document if its value is empty string (`optional: true`). We can catch and prevent this.

```js
  fileNo: {
    type: String,
    label: 'File No.',
    autoValue() {
      if (this.isInsert && (this.value == null || !this.value.length)) {
        return '-';
      }
      if (this.isUpdate && this.isSet && this.operator === '$unset') {
        return { $set: '-' };
      }
    },
    optional: true
  }
```

**Added**: documentation used to write this answer (code works as expected; tested locally):

- [aldeed:meteor-collection2#autovalue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#autovalue)
- [aldeed:meteor-simple-schema#autovalue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue)

Comment: thanks a ton again. You saved a lot of my time, this was very narrow case that I was unable to solve :)

Comment: @AnkurSoni You're welcome :) Reading docs thoroughly helps a lot ;)

Comment: can you also point the link and line no of docs in your answer?

Comment: @AnkurSoni Updated my answer

Comment: are you available for contracting?

Comment: @AnkurSoni Sorry, I'm too busy on other projects :) But thanks, maybe later.